# Sort ElasticSearch based on number of objects of array type field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the elastic search cluster of the form:

```
{
    "_id":"xxxx"
    "contents":[
        {
            "name":"abc",
            "age":"24"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id":"yyyy"
    "contents":[
        {
            "name":"xyz",
            "age":"25"
        },
        {
            "name":"pqr",
            "age":"29"
        },
    ]

}
```

I have to perform a sort based query on the size of the object array field 'contents'.

I have tried:

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "match_all": {} 
    },
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "script": "doc['contents.name'].values.size()",
            "order": "desc",
            "type" : "string",
        }
    }
}
```

The above query sometime gives me the correct result, but most of the times it fails to give the results in sorted order.

Comment: do yo tried using `type : number` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that also

Answer (score 1):

Your `contents` field is an array, not an object. So when you try and access contents.name in your script it's undefined. You should get the size of the `contents` array:

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {} 
  },
  "sort" : {
    "_script" : {
      "script": "doc['contents'].values.size()",
      "order": "desc",
      "type" : "string",
    }
  }
}
```